Multiple imputation with some missing baseline data and with some missing longitudinal data
How shall I impute the data in the following situation: I have some baseline covariates collected and longitudinal data. Both baseline covariates and longitudinal data have some missing data.
Shall I impute first baseline covariates using regression imputation of the missing baseline covariates based on all other variables.
And then when baseline covariates are imputed, use multiple imputations for longitudinal outcome?

In general, you should impute all those missing values, both predictors and outcomes, together. Stef van Buuren shows how in Flexible Imputation of Missing Data. He quotes Donal Rubin at the beginning of Chapter 2 to explain why that's important:

Imputing one value for a missing datum cannot be correct in general, because we don’t know what value to impute with certainty (if we did, it wouldn’t be missing).

That said, in some circumstances it might be good enough to use single imputation. See Chapter 3 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies, with a summary in Section 3.11.
It also might not be necessary to impute the missing outcome observations at all, depending on how you are modeling time with your longitudinal data. With a flexible model of time it might be possible to use the data you have and not worry about having some missing time points for some individuals. That's not possible if you are doing a classic multivariate linear regression, but there can be better choices than that. See Chapter 7 of the Harrell reference.
